# Find file by a part of its content

Tags: files, search, recursive

I have many files in a specific repository and i must find a file which has a specific string in its content (actually referencing the file `Version.cc.in`). What is the best solution to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use grep:

```
grep "text" /path/to/directory/*
```

For recusive search you could use `-r` option for grep:

```
grep -r "text" /path/to/directory/*
```

or `**` in path:

```
grep "text" /path/to/directory/**/*
```

but, availability of `**` operator is shell dependent - as far I know it is in `zsh` and `bash` (4 only?), it may not be available in other shells.

Comment: And what's with a recursive search?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Or you can run `grep -r "text" /path/to/directory`.

Comment: @Caleb: changed...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool called [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/). It is descibed as:

> ack is a tool like grep, designed for
>   programmers with large trees of
>   heterogeneous source code.

Basically it is similar to grep in that it searches files for patterns, but with a few key differences. Namely, it searches recursively and ignores version control and backup files by default (e.g. CVS, .svn, foo~, #foo#). And since it is built with Perl it is cross-platform. It also allows you to specify particular file types within a directory to search, so if you only want to search Perl files you could type

```
ack --perl pattern
```

If interested there is a list of the "top 10 reasons to use ack instead of grep" on the [ack homepage](http://betterthangrep.com/). Plus, there is a [Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572).

Comment: Looks interesting, but I don't see the top 10 reasons list. Why not link to it directly?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Scroll down till _Top 10 reasons to use ack instead of grep._ where 13 reasons are listed.

Answer (score 1):

There is another tool similar to [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), called [The Silver Searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/2011/12/27/the-silver-searcher-better-than-ack/). The developer claims that it "is like ack, but better. It’s fast. It’s damn fast. The only thing faster is stuff that builds indicies beforehand, like Exuberant Ctags."

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find and list the file, not the actual contents, then use the `-l` option with grep:

```
grep -lr Version.cc.in $(pwd)/*
```

Which will give you a list of all files and the absolute path to them (assuming the files are in directories/subdirectories of your current working directory).